# The most reliable way of identifying deer antler measurements?

Tags: zoology, ethology, experimental-design, measurement

I am creating a (theoretical) study on how males use antlers to assess fellow males' abilities. I thus would need to have accurate measurements of antlers, including length, width, number of tines etc.

The papers I am reading are either really vague, using data already available, or they are relying on antlers which are cast each year to obtain the measurements. In a real life study, the last would be least intrusive and the most ethical, but would it be the most reliable?

I am equally unsure of the efficacy of waiting for deer to cast their antlers to then obtain measurements, as well as having the issue of changes / potential misidentification. I could take the DNA from the antler and use that to identify the deer that they came from.

Does anyone have any experience of this / any input as to what would be the most ethical, reliable method of doing this?

I understand there are confounding factors in this study, with other traits likely affecting deer fights. They seem to be largely un-dealt with in the literature, and I am giving them thought also.
With thanks.

Comment: Since antler size is important for hunting regulations, I imagine hunters and related organizations (such as rangers or game wardens) might compile such data. Hunted animals could also provide a source of data that does not require antlers to be shed.